# Winapi TextOut() displaying nothing on the first call, working fine just afterwards

Tags: c++, winapi

I found a mystery within my old code:

```
void Viewer::ShowWarningAndRedraw() //called when zoom too big
{
    //clearing the view
    SelectObject(hDC_, GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
    FillRect(hDC_, rect_, WHITE_BRUSH);

    CString msg = _T("Too zoomed");
    SelectObject(hDC_, GetStockObject(BLACK_PEN));

    /*auto res1 =*/ TextOut(hDC_, 35, rect_.Height()/2 - 5, msg, int(_tcslen(msg)));
    /*auto res2 =*/ TextOut(hDC_, 35, rect_.Height()/2 - 5, msg, int(_tcslen(msg)));//not sure why, but only the second call actually works. both return success.

    Sleep(1000);//flashing the message briefly

    DrawFullView();//redrawing
}
```

and indeed, only the second call actually works while both succeed (return 1). Why does the first call produce no visible output? The parameters are obviously correct (the second exactly identical call displays the desired message).

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Be sure to read the Microsoft docs for TextOut() to see why SetTextAlign() is relevant to what it does.  TA_UPDATECP will have an affect on multiple calls.

Comment: How do you know that the first call fail?

Comment: @HansPassant that cannot be the reason: elsewhere I call multiple Textouts and no updating occurs

Comment: @manuell: I tried (1)calling it only once, (2)calling it twice with different positions, (3)stepping through while looking to my output field. The first call simply produces zero visible output.

Comment: You may be seeing the effect of gdi batching. Sleeping on a UI thread is a bad idea. You should set a timer for 1 second and resume there. That will also solve the problem since returning to the message loop allows the batch to complete.

Comment: @Mori personal advice: "always do as Raymond said". Replace the `Sleep` call by a `SetTimer` call

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you, it sounds reasonable. I replaced the Sleep() with clock_t and a while loop, works fine apart from solving the original problem -- the first call to TextOut() still produces nothing:/

Comment: anyway, waiting is not the cause, I tried to remove it and simply keep the text indefinitely, the first call is *still* ignored.

Comment: Is `DrawFullView()` overwriting the text? What happens if you take out the `DrawFullView()`? Is the text being overwritten by your `WM_PAINT` handler? Painting outside your `WM_PAINT` is highly irregular.

Comment: Yes, DrawFullView() starts by clearing the full rect_ area, that is also the reason for the Sleep() function (or other timeout). Without timeout (and without redrawing of course) the behaviour is still the same, first TextOut produces nothing, second (and third etc if present) displays message as expected.

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), since I cannot repro it in my environment.

Comment: Sleeping (or busy-waiting) on the UI thread will not allow the GDI batch to complete, so nothing will be rendered during the sleep or busy-wait. You need to make DrawFullView draw the text. Painting outside the paint cycle is nonstandard and you will run into problems like this when you try.